# MySQL Load data Statements

Tags: mysql, sql, import

i have some large SQL-Files with many "INSERT INTO" Statements.

My Command:

```
mysql> Load data local infile 'values.sql' into table test_table;
```

My Statements look like these:

```
INSERT INTO test_table(column1,column2) VALUES('1','2');
INSERT INTO test_table(column1,column2) VALUES('3','4');
```

When i run this Command, my test_table column1 will be filled with the complete Statement.
Whats my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

load data is for stuff like CSV.

You have actual SQL INSERT statements.

Try:

`mysql -u USERNAME -p DATABASENAME < values.sql`

Comment: How slow is slow? How many entries does it do per second? How big is the .sql file?

Comment: sql file is 250mb
200 entrys per second?
load data just needs 1 or 2 minutes for such a large file. i think i convert them to a csv file.

Comment: How long did it take it to run through the whole thing? How many rows did it insert?

Comment: Did not test it. There are nearly 3 Million rows in the file. would be way to long. converting to csv and import via load data is much faster

Answer (score 1):

From MySQL reference [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html):

> The LOAD DATA INFILE statement reads rows from a text file into a
>   table at a very high speed. The file name must be given as a literal
>   string.

This means that MySQL expects rows with column values in that file, not SQL statements to execute.

Check [Executing SQL Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/batch-commands.html) to see the way to do what You want.